# Windows, C#: reading eventlog entries from active AND saved logs

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I know that I can read the Security logs of a Windows PC using:

```
var securityLog = new EventLog("security");
foreach (EventLogEntry entry in securityLog.Entries) {
    ...
}
```

The `entry` item contains all the interesting log fields I expect to see like: `InstanceId`, `Message` and others.  What I want to do now is read the same things from an event log that was saved to disk as an `.evtx` file.

I have seen suggestions for using

```
string xpathQuery = "*";

var eventsQuery = args.Length == 0
    ? new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, xpathQuery)
    : new EventLogQuery(args[0], PathType.FilePath, xpathQuery);

using (var eventLogReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery)) {
    EventLogRecord entry;

    while ((entry = (EventLogRecord) eventLogReader.ReadEvent()) != null) {
        ...
    }
}
```

but the `entry` in the second version doesn't contain the same members/values as the first example.  I totally dig that I am confused and am looking at the problem the wrong way.

How should one go about reading the actual per record content from either an active or saved system log?

Or, can I go from an `EventLogRecord` to an `EventLogEntry`?  I have not seen that conversion method yet.

Comment: This is not a full answer but I am partway there.  A buddy found that in my second approach I can get the event "message" using `entry.FormatDescription()`. `entry.Id` is the `InstanceId`. There is only one date field that i see though.  There is a set of "Properties" but i am not sure how to access them in a named way.

But i am closer